# Should I write factories or use conditional registration in DI when I want to resolve dependencies with diffrent implementations on diffrent types?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac, simple-injector

Let's assume I have following situation:

I have `Downloader` type that has 3 dependencies like `IDep1`, `IDep2`, `IDep3`. These dependencies has 2 implementations. For `IDep1` is `Dep1Impl1` and `Dep1Impl2` etc. Depending on type that has `Downloader` as dependency I wanna resolve `Downloader` with diffrent `IDep`'s implementations.

What is best practice to do something like this? It's better to write a factories for `IDep`'s and call `Downloader` with optimal parameters or try conditional registration in DI? Or there's better solution for this?

EDIT:

For clarification `Downloader` is dependency in ASP.NET MVC Controllers. On diffrent controllers I wanna diffrent implementations of `IDep`'s in `Downloader`.

EDIT2:

I know in compile time what dependencies should go for each `Downloader`. And these dependencies are fixed for each controller where `Downloader` is dependency. So I think Scott's anwser is best solution for that kind of problem.

Comment: How are you determining which implementation of `Downloader` is needed for each Controller?  If it's based on some known parameters you have access to at runtime, an abstract factory may a solid choice.  If it's simply a declarative scenario where ControllerA always gets the same implementation and ControllerB always gets a different one, then Scott Hannen has the best option.

Comment: The correct answer highly depends on the specific use case. Please describe what determines who get which Downloader. Is this based on application configuration? Do you have multiple different Downloaders in the same application? Do the consumers of Downloader still work correctly when they get a different Downloader?

Comment: Did you see [this FAQ?](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem there, if I understand correctly, is that you want more than one class to depend on `Downloader`. And the class that depends on `Downloader` determines what type of dependency `Downloader` receives.

I don't think a factory is a good solution for that because

- The classes that depend on `Downloader` shouldn't know about the internal dependencies of `Downloader`
- `Downloader` shouldn't know what's depending on *it* to be able to pass that detail to a factory.

You can do that but it would get convoluted. You'd need a *factory* factory.

It sounds like what you want is to have pre-defined compositions of `Downloader` - one that depends on one implementation, another than depends on another implementation.

You can do that with Windsor (similar for Unity) like this:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IDownloaderDependency,DownloaderDependencyTypeA>
        .Named("DownloaderDependencyTypeA"),
    Component.For<IDownloader,Downloader>
        .Named("DownloaderForClassA")
        .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(
            typeof(IDownloaderDependency),
            "DownloaderDependencyTypeA")),
    Component.For<ClassA>
        .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(
            typeof(IDownloader),
            "DownloaderForClassA"))
)
```

So what you're doing is defining a way that `Downloader` can be composed, using a specific dependency type, and then saying to use that composition of `Downloader` for `ClassA`.

That way `ClassA` gets the right `Downloader` with the right dependencies, but from its perspective all it knows is that it depends on `Downloader`. It doesn't (and shouldn't) know about the dependencies *within* `Downloader`.